# I find it hard implementing a function which replaces the 'chars' with the alphabetically corresponding 'periodic table' element

Tags: python

```
from random import choice, choices, randint


def periodic_table_word_char(word):
    chars = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
    periodic_table = ['Ac','Ag','Al','Am','Ar','As','At','Au','B','Ba','Be','Bh','Bi','Bk','Br','C','Ca','Cd','Ce','Cf','Cl','Cm','Cn','Co','Cr','Cs','Cu','Db','Ds','Dy','Er','Es','Eu','F','Fe','Fl','Fm','Fr','Ga','Gd','Ge','H ','He ','Hf','Hg','Ho','Hs','I','In','Ir','K','Kr','La','Li','Lr','Lu','Lv','Mc','Md','Mg','Mn','Mo','Mt','N','Na','Nb','Nd','Ne','Nh','Ni','No','Np','O','Og','Os','P','Pa','Pb','Pd','Pm','Po','Pr','Pt','Pu','Ra','Rb','Re','Rf','Rg','Rh','Rn','Ru','S','Sb','Sc','Se','Sg','Si','Sm','Sn ','Sr','Ta','Tb','Tc','Te','Th','Ti','Tl','Tm','Ts','U','V','W','Xe','Y','Yb','Zn','Zr']

    #word_modified = word.replace(chars, periodic_table)
```

The above is a sort of idea I had, but I don't know how to implement it right so the character is replaced alphabetically by the element in the 'periodic_table'

```
    print(word_modified)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = input("Enter any word:")
    periodic_table_word_char(w)
```

Comment: what is the correspondence between items in `chars` and in `periodic_table`? The second has much more elements.

Comment: Trying to understand the problem, are you trying to make it so that the user could input 'a' and get back 'Ac'?

Comment: Also why are you importing all those functions from `random`?

Comment: the imports were there because of initial ideas, the idea i have is for a 'filter' that replaces a character i.e. 'a' with Au or As or Ag. Would be cool if it could choose it depending on more than one word i.e. the word 'agriculture' being replaced with 'AgRhICuLiTiURhEr' based on the periodic table

Comment: So you want to replace the letter with a random element that stars with that letter?

Comment: yes, that's the idea

Comment: @Colver If you want something that "sounds like" the original string instead of just picking something with the same initial character, it gets more complicated. Please describe what you really want to do so this doesn't evolve into one of those "thanks for the answer, but my actual problem is..." things.

Answer (score 1):

You need a one-to-many mapping, so use a dictionary that maps each character to all the elements that start with that character.
Then you can make a random choice among the values a character maps to.

Example:

```
import random
table = {'a': (1,2,3), 'b': (4,5), 'c': (6,7,8)}
for c in "aaabbbc":
    print(random.choice(table[c]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
import random
random.seed(42)


periodic_table = ['Ac', 'Ag', 'Al', 'Am', 'Ar', 'As', 'At', 'Au', 'B', 'Ba', 'Be', 'Bh', 'Bi', 'Bk', 'Br', 'C',
                  'Ca', 'Cd', 'Ce', 'Cf', 'Cl', 'Cm', 'Cn', 'Co', 'Cr', 'Cs', 'Cu', 'Db', 'Ds', 'Dy', 'Er', 'Es',
                  'Eu', 'F', 'Fe', 'Fl', 'Fm', 'Fr', 'Ga', 'Gd', 'Ge', 'H ', 'He ', 'Hf', 'Hg', 'Ho', 'Hs', 'I',
                  'In', 'Ir', 'K', 'Kr', 'La', 'Li', 'Lr', 'Lu', 'Lv', 'Mc', 'Md', 'Mg', 'Mn', 'Mo', 'Mt', 'N',
                  'Na', 'Nb', 'Nd', 'Ne', 'Nh', 'Ni', 'No', 'Np', 'O', 'Og', 'Os', 'P', 'Pa', 'Pb', 'Pd', 'Pm',
                  'Po', 'Pr', 'Pt', 'Pu', 'Ra', 'Rb', 'Re', 'Rf', 'Rg', 'Rh', 'Rn', 'Ru', 'S', 'Sb', 'Sc', 'Se',
                  'Sg', 'Si', 'Sm', 'Sn ', 'Sr', 'Ta', 'Tb', 'Tc', 'Te', 'Th', 'Ti', 'Tl', 'Tm', 'Ts', 'U', 'V',
                  'W', 'Xe', 'Y', 'Yb', 'Zn', 'Zr']

to_element = {}
for element in periodic_table:
    to_element.setdefault(element[0].lower(), []).append(element)

def periodic_table_word_char(word):
    return ''.join(random.choice(to_element.get(c, [c])) for c in word)


result = periodic_table_word_char('agriculture')
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
AgGaRgICeULaTsURnEr
```

The idea is that `to_element` is a mapping from letters to elements, then you can use that mapping to choose the corresponding elements for each letter.

Answer (score 0):

building on molbdnilo

```
import random
table = {'a': (1,2,3), 'b': (4,5), 'c': (6,7,8)}
ns = ''
for c in "aaabbbc":
    ns+=str(random.choice(table[c]))

print(ns)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I think the best way to do this is to actually create a list of lists, where each sublist has elements that start with the same letter. As in:

`periodic_table = [ ["Ac", "Ag", "Al", "Am", "Ar", "As", "At", "Au"], 
                    ["B", "Ba", "Be", "Bh", "Bi", "Bk", "Br"], 
                    ... ]`

Since you have a mapping of letters to first letters of elements already, you know how to index into the outer list (alphabetical ordering). So, if you wanted all elements that started with "A", you could do

`elementsStartingWithA = periodic_table[0]`

Then you need to generate a random number between 0 and the length of your smaller list, and exchange the letter you're looking up your function's input with the corresponding random string value from the smaller list. So, if your input word was the article `a` and your randomly generated index into `elementsStartingWithA` was the integer `3`, you'd return the string `Am`.